# The resolvent of an operator commutes with it.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $\Phi : X \rightarrow X$ a bounded operator.
Let also $R(\cdot,\Phi) : \rho(\Phi) \rightarrow B(X)$ the resolvent operator of $\Phi$ defined in the usual way as $R(\lambda,\Phi) := (\lambda I -\Phi)^{-1}$ for $\lambda \in \rho(\Phi)$.

Is it always true, or under which assumptions, does $\Phi$ commute with its resolvent?
And if yes, how to show it?

I think that maybe the Neumann series plays a role in an eventual proof.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have 
$$
I=R(\lambda,\Phi)\,(\lambda I - \Phi)=\lambda\,R(\lambda,\Phi) - R(\lambda,\Phi)\Phi.
$$You also have 
$$
I=(\lambda I - \Phi)\,R(\lambda,\Phi)=\lambda\,R(\lambda,\Phi) - \Phi\,R(\lambda,\Phi).
$$
Subtract, and you get
$$
R(\lambda,\Phi)\Phi=\Phi\,R(\lambda,\Phi).
$$
In general, any algebraic expression on $\Phi$ will commute with $\Phi$. And then you can move up from there to functional calculus (which would give a different prove of the equality).